# Unable to loop single react component

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

I'm trying to loop my StudentInfo component so a blurb of information can be repeated down an array of 25 objects provided through an API for each object/a student (name, email, company, etc.) I'm not
sure where I'm going wrong; here is my attempted loop via the map function:

```
export default function StudentList() {
  let students = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="StudentList">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          {students.map(function (student, index) {
            if (index <= 25) {
              return (
                <div className="col" key={index}>
                  <StudentInfo data={student} />
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone see what I'm missing or what I might have skipped? I usually assume that I must be doing something wrong because I'm still new at React and trying to adapt other code I used for a weather forecast app to be used for this, but I don't think it's translating over well.

When I run this, I see the first object twice, i.e. Name, Email, Company, etc. it shows the info for the same person twice, rather than the first person, the second person, etc. I want to be able to see this pull all the objects from the array.

Here is the information I'm pulling to return as an entry on student info:

```
export default function StudentInfo() {
  const [info, addInfo] = useState(" ");

  function setInfo(response) {
    addInfo({
      number: response.data.students[0].id,
      first: response.data.students[0].firstName,
      last: response.data.students[0].lastName,
      email: response.data.students[0].email,
      company: response.data.students[0].company,
      skill: response.data.students[0].skill,
      average: response.data.students[0].grades[0],
    });
  }

  let url = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
  axios.get(url).then(setInfo);

  return (
    <div className="StudentInfo">
      <h1>{info.number}.</h1>
      <h2>
        Name: {info.first} {info.last}
      </h2>
      <h2>Email: {info.email}</h2>
      <h2>Company: {info.company}</h2>
      <h2>Skill: {info.skill}</h2>
      <h2>Average: {info.average}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using "if (index <= 25)" as there are 25 total entries that I want showing, but as I mentioned, I have no doubt I'm going about this incorrectly. I want this to loop through all 25 objects with the above information, as I keep saying. I'm sorry if I'm not speaking technically enough to be understood, as *I am still learning*.

I just want this to return 25 times with info from each object so that it's all listed out.

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfAOY.png)

**UPDATE**
I've been tinkering and was able to repeat the entry, however I'm now having trouble getting the unique information, i.e. I'm only seeing the first entry over and over. I'm not sure how to reiterate with new information since it's only going to response.data.students[0]. This is what my code looks like now, where the mapping is:

```
export default function StudentList() {
  let [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  let [students, setStudent] = useState(" ");
  function doInfo(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    setStudent(response.data.students[0].id);
    setLoaded(true);
  }

  if (loaded) {
    return (
      <div className="StudentList">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            {students.map(function (id) {
              return <StudentInfo data={id} />;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    let url = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
    axios.get(url).then(doInfo);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me code it so it runs through all 25 entries, not just the first one?

Comment: We need some more info. Why do you think that you are doing something wrong? What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your quesiton to include more details.

Comment: .map method for array can't run on condition. It loops through all items in the array. and also useState return array with state (which you use as students) and a function setStudents (call whatever you want. ) then you have to update the state from this function.

Comment: why you use this condition ? `if (index <= 25)`

Comment: updated the question - please let me know if it's still unclear

Comment: "there are 25 total entries that I want showing" Then you should just take the first 25 entries in the array with `slice()`. If you still need help, we need more information. Please answer all of my questions in my first comment.

Comment: okay... i had answered in the first edit but i updated again. i'm not familiar with slice() so i'm open to hearing more.

Comment: My mistake. I missed where you said "When I run this, I see the first object twice" in the previous edit. I suggest doing `console.log(students)` to check if it what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code.

## UseState

React useState hook returns an array with a value and a setter method to update the state [useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
const [students, setStudents] = useState(null);
```

## Iterate over null values

If your state starts with a null value you will not be able to iterate over it. To avoid getting an error you should make sure to use the map operator when your state has a value.

```
{students && students.map(function (student, index) {
   ...
})}
```

## Handling side effects

You should move your API request (and set your info state) inside of a useEffect ([useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)). This way you will set those values asynchronously after the component is mounted.

```
export default function StudentInfo() {
  const [info, addInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchInfo() {
      const url = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students"; //should be a constant outside the component
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      addInfo({
        number: response.data.students[0].id,
        first: response.data.students[0].firstName,
        last: response.data.students[0].lastName,
        email: response.data.students[0].email,
        company: response.data.students[0].company,
        skill: response.data.students[0].skill,
        average: response.data.students[0].grades[0],
    });
    fetchInfo();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="StudentInfo">
     {info &&
      <h1>{info.number}.</h1>
      <h2>
        Name: {info.first} {info.last}
      </h2>
      <h2>Email: {info.email}</h2>
      <h2>Company: {info.company}</h2>
      <h2>Skill: {info.skill}</h2>
      <h2>Average: {info.average}</h2>
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function StudentList() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
```

Check React's documentation [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Also check if it cannot be declared that way, you need to use a ternary if. Check that part in React's documenation [Conditional rending](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
        {students.map(function (student, index) {
        index <= 25 && (
            <div className="col" key={index}>
              <StudentInfo data={student} />
            </div>
          );
```

Comment: Please use english to answer.